# its a 'x' which floats on the output screen and moves in real time

Tags: c++

it doesn't work,the code seems right and there are no errors/ warnings while compilation.

tried some minor adjustments and different approaches but the problem persists

```
void ctrl()                               // void main calls ctrl.
{

    int x=10,y=10,s=1;

    print(x,y);          //this fn just clrscr + prints 'x' +getch 

    char c;

    do
    {
          cin>>c;      

        switch(c=getch())        
        {
            case'w':
                print(x,y-=s);
                break;

            case's':
                print(x,y+=s);
                break;

            case'a':
                print(x-=s,y);
                break;

            case'd':
                print(x+=s,y);
                break;
        }

    }
    while(c!='x');
}
```

expected result is an 'x' which moves accordingly when ;'w','s','a','d' are pressed, but i get a 'x' which only does that once every(not exact! not a math thing) 10 outputs other times the inputs 'w', etc. are printed, also most of the times it alternatively moves(which is right) then prints(which is wrong).

Answer (score -1):

```
cin>>c;
```

Delete this line. It's redundant since you already have `c=getch()` to read input.

Comment: @DragonFodder you'lll need to rethink - which is a good thing since your loop has a few things that can go wrong. The obvious is `while(c!='x');`. What if the stream(s) suddenly closes?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo sir, i dont know what you mean by streams but i can try some other way to end the loop( although i dont know if the loop is the problem) thanks

Comment: @John mentioned a very importat stream extraction in _your_: code (the `cin>>c;`).

Comment: `c=getch()` is already asking for input. Having both `getch()` and `cin` is redundant.